# JavaFX TableView with ChangeListener for multiple selection

Tags: javafx, tableview, selecteditem, multipleselection, changelistener

I want to listen for selection changes on a table view in JavaFX 8. If I add a ChangeListener to the `selectedItemProperty` (or selectedIndexProperty) of the MultipleSelectionModel it does not fire in the following case:
Multiple lines are already selected and now I select a new single line. If this line is the last line that has been selected before, it does not react. This is because the selectedItemProperty contains only one item and not the list of all that are selected. But unfortunately there is no selected**Items**Property which is strange because the method `getSelectedItems()` exists. I don't know where to add the listener instead to make it work in any case.

Here is an example code:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MultipleSelectionTest extends Application
{
    private ListView<Integer> list = new ListView<>();
    private TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
    private TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Numbers");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        HBox box = new HBox(list, table);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(box, 300, 500));
        initializeTable();
        initializeList();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initializeTable()
    {
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        table.getColumns().add(column1);
        column1.setCellValueFactory(s -> new SimpleStringProperty(s.getValue()));
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"));
    }

    private void initializeList()
    {
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((property, oldValue, newValue) ->
        {
            ObservableList<Integer> convertedItems = FXCollections.observableList(
                table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
                .stream()
                .map(this::convertNumber)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

            list.setItems(convertedItems);
        });
    }

    private int convertNumber(String expression)
    {
        switch (expression)
        {
            case "One": return 1;
            case "Two": return 2;
            case "Three": return 3;
            case "Four": return 4;
            case "Five": return 5;
            case "Six": return 6;
            case "Seven": return 7;
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Note that the ListView in this sample is only for visual purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a `selectedItemsProperty` - `getSelectedItems` returns an `ObservableList` to which you can add a listener.

Having a property for this would imply the list object changed, but what in fact happens is that the list stays the same *object*, but it's contents change .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more complete solution which was figured out thanks to the pointer by SillyFly's response.

In my example the assume the table was set up to work with an arbitrary class Person which defined a first name, last name and email.

```
//Set the table to multi selection mode
table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode( SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

//Regiseter the listener on the ObervableList<Person>
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().addListener(multiSelection);


  /**A listener for list selections, multiple selections in the TableView**/
     ListChangeListener< Person> multiSelection = new ListChangeListener<Person>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(  ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Person> changed){
            for( Person p : changed.getList())
                System.out.println(p);
        } 
     };
```